# Doubt on a hard finite sum

Tags: analysis

I'm reading an article on wikipedia about Cauchy product of series: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product.

My doubt is in the part of generalized form of the cauchy product:

Let $\sum_{k_1}^{\infty}a_{1,k_1} \cdots \sum_{k_n}^{\infty}a_{n,k_n}$ be $n$ series with complex coefficients, from which all except the
${\displaystyle n}$th one converge absolutely, and the ${\displaystyle n}$th one converges.

The claim is that:$$\prod_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{k_j = 0}^{\infty}a_{j,k_j}= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{0 \leq k_{1} \cdots +k_{n} \leq N}\prod_{v=1}^{n}a_{v,k_v}\tag{1}$$.

To show that, they start with an affirmation:
$$\sum_{0 \leq k_{1} \cdots +k_{n} \leq N} \prod_{v=1}^{n}a_{v,k_v}=\sum_{k_1=0}^{N} \sum_{k_2=0}^{k_1} \cdots \sum_{k_n=0}^{k_{n-1}}a_{1,k_n}.a_{2, k_{n-1} -k_n}. \  \cdots \ .a_{n, k_1 - k_2}\tag{2}$$

I didn't understand what (1) and (2) means because of the summation with an inequality on the index, and because of the $k_n$ as a index and the same time indexed. Please, could anybody help me to undersand?

Comment: The sum $\sum_{0 \leq k_{1} \cdots +k_{n} \leq N}$ indicates that you are summing over all integers $k_i$ within the given constraint. The right hand side is simply a nested summation. To visualize what's going on you can consider $n=2$. Then essentially you have different ways to sum in the allowed regions. It's a bit like a change of variable in an integral.

Comment: Would you please write how would be on the n=2 case? I dint'd get it yet...